# How to diff only the first line of two files?

Tags: linux, command-line, diff

I want to diff only the first line of two files, as opposed to the entire file. How would I do that? I only need a solution for the the first line, but if you could specify the number of lines that would be a much better answer.

So diff would return no differences between the following two files:

```
a
1
2
```

and:

```
a
3
4
```

Comment: did that work for you...?

Comment: @nerdwaller Yup, accepted.

Comment: cool beans. Was trying to think of other options, fortunately that's not necessary.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here you go:

```
diff <(head -n 1 file1) <(head -n 1 file2)
```

(this would return nothing what-so-ever).

```
diff <(head -n 2 file1) <(head -n 2 file2)

Returns:
2c2
< 1
---
> 3
```

You could incorporate that into a script to do the things you mention.

```
#!/bin/bash

fileOne=${1}
fileTwo=${2}
numLines=${3:-"1"}

diff <(head -n ${numLines} ${fileOne}) <(head -n ${numLines} ${fileTwo})
```

To use that, just make the script executable with `chmod +x nameofscript.sh` and then to execute, `./nameofscript.sh ~/file1 ~/Docs/file2` That leaves the default # of lines at 1, if you want more append a number to the end of that command.

(Or you could do switches in your script with -f1 file1 -f2 file2 -n 1, but I don't recall of the top of my head the case statement for that).

`head` returns from the beginning the # of lines as suggested by `-n`.  If you were to want to do reverse, it would be `tail -n ${numLines}` (tail does from the end back the number of lines).

Edit 5/10/16:

This is specific to Bash (and compatible shells). If you need to use this from something else:

```
bash -c 'diff <(...) <(...)'
```

Comment: How would that work for recursive diff when I need to diff two directories?

Comment: @lanoxx `diff -r dir1 dir2` for directories, to limit it you'll probably want to pipe that to something else. If you have specifics open a new question and give a link here.

Comment: Well basically the same question just recursively: Diff only ( the first n lines | everything except the first n lines) for for all files in two directories.

Comment: @lanoxx like I said, make a new question and link it. It's best practice for the super user community instead of expanding the scope of some other user's question.

Comment: Here you go: http://superuser.com/q/982063/194998

Comment: I get "missing name for redirect" when I try this command

Comment: @Veridian What shell are you using?  This is bash specific, so you may need to call `bash -c "diff <(...) <(...)"`

Comment: I'm using the tcsh shell

Comment: @Veridian - Yeah, process substitutions work differently there (I'm not sure how they do at all), `bash -c "" ` will work or you need to find the same functionality in the different shell.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? `diff < $(head file1) < $(head file2)`. I thought the `$(command)` notation would work like this. But it throws an `ambiguous redirect` error.

Answer (score -2):

diff -U (n of lines) file1 file2

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you elaborate a little on the `-U` argument? :)