# How do I recursively diff two directores and ignore the first n lines of each file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, diff

This question is similar to [How to diff only the first line of two files?](https://superuser.com/q/511396/194998), but recursively. I would like to diff two directories but:

- diff only the first N lines of each file in the two directories
- diff everything except the first N lines of each file in the two directories

Comment: Normally you can compare using `diff -r dir1 dir2`. You may also play with `-I RE` option to ignore certain matching lines.

Comment: Why you want to ignore first n lines? What's your motivation/scenario?

Comment: Because they contain a unimportant metadata, such as time, date, title which I am not interested in, instead I only want to compare the data of the files.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion for you is to use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/). It works from the command-line as well.

It has the following [features](http://meldmerge.org/features.html) which can interest you:

- Compare two or three directories file-by-file, showing new, missing, and altered files.
- Use the built-in regex text filtering to ignore uninteresting differences.

The only thing which you need to do is to figure out the right regex patterns which can be used to ignore the unimportant data (depending on the syntax of your metadata which you want to ignore).

Answer (score 0):

These two loops use `diff -qr` to do an initial diff, principally
to get the filenames easily, then do an individual diff on the
found pair of files. `sed` is used to clear the first N lines, or
to keep only the first N lines. First to clear N lines:

```
N=2
diff -qr dir1 dir2 |
grep '^Files.*differ' |
while read x a x b x
do  diff --label "$a" --label "$b" -u <(sed "1,${N}s/.*//" <"$a") <(sed "1,${N}s/.*//" <"$b")
done
```

And this to keep N:

```
diff -qr dir1 dir2 |
grep '^Files.*differ' |
while read x a x b x
do  diff --label "$a" --label "$b" -u <(sed -n "1,${N}p" <"$a") <(sed -n "1,${N}p" <"$b")
done
```

This assumes no spaces/tabs in filenames.